# Is there any tools to check what is happening in Kohana at Auth?

Tags: frameworks, kohana, authentication

So, there is problem - I have the order to write web-app on Kohana (no choice) and until yesterday I had no experience with this framework (only in Rails). But anyway I googled and created the authentification on site via net steps:
1: using standart SQL-code in Kohana I created tables for Auth.
2: tutn on ORM and Auth
3: create action login()

```
public function action_login()
{
    $auth = Auth::instance();



    if ($auth->logged_in())
    {
        return $this->request->redirect("welcome/view");
    };

    if ($_POST)
    {
        $user = ORM::factory("user");

        $status = $auth->login($_POST["username"],$_POST["password"]);


        if ($status)
        {
            $this->request->redirect("welcome/view");
        }
        else
        {

            echo "Failed to login";
        }
    };
    $this->response->body(View::factory("login"));
}
```

But whatever I do I get echo *"Failed to login";*.

Is there any tools to define what's wrong happening ? Some logs ? 
Or, may be, I do something wrong at common....

Comment: Do you include the session module? How did you create the user? Did you [configure the auth module](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/auth/config)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: no there are no obvious tools to dig into Auth. You're best off going into modules/auth and look into the files and dump out information to Kohana::log or Kohana::debug to debug the errors.

I think the problem with your code is that in Kohana 3.2, $_POST is unset.  You should use this instead:

```
 $status = $auth->login($this->request->post("username"), $this->request->post("password"));
```

Should work after that.